# gynandromorph bee

Tags: meaning-in-context

> One other Megalopta gynandromorph has shown its face to scientists before: a male-female hybrid in a closely related sweat bee species called Megalopta genalis, identified in 1999. In the two decades since, STRI researchers have collected and analyzed tens of thousands of other bees **without uncovering a second example**—making the new Megalopta amoena specimen’s recent and serendipitous appearance a welcome encore act, says Krichilsky.
>
> ...
>
> Though the researchers aren’t sure how exactly this bizarre bee came to be, studies in similar insects might provide some hints. Several years ago, another team of scientists led by University of Sydney bee expert Benjamin Oldroyd **analyzed the genes of several honeybee gynandromorphs** and found that the male-female hybrids were likely the result of a developmental mishap.

I don't get it, doesn't it say no a second example found in 20 years since, how come then they have several cases to study?

article link : https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smithsonian-institution/meet-bee-body-s-half-male-half-female-180974553/

Comment: They are talking about different kinds of bees. The scientists have not found a gynandromorph Megalopta bee for 20 years, but apparently it is fairly common in honeybees.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a matter of learning English.  This appears to be a question of understanding bee biology.  Apart from the fact that the article was written in English, there is no Language learning content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unique example seems to be a sweat bee, megalopta. The multiple examples seem to be honeybees, apis. The article says the latter are "similar insects" that may provide hints about the unique occurrence in the sweat bee.